# Column disappears when I use a group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fgfz.png)

I need to find the tuition fee for each student displayed with the name of the student and when I use group by in my query, I geteither the name of the student or the student_num but not both. This is the query i used

```
select e.student_num as StudentID, s.student_name as Name,
sum(c.num_credits*450) as Tuition from students s, enrolls e, sections se, courses c 
where e.student_num = s.student_num 
and e.section_id=se.section_id 
and se.course_num=c.course_num
group by s.student_name;
```

Now this table gives the correct student id and the correct tuition cost but doesn't display the name in the name column Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks. I have also attached the schema for reference

Comment: Your query should return an error because the `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by` columns.

Comment: I see. I mixed up my problem a little.  I get an empty student ID, the correct name column and the correct corresponding tuition fee @GordonLinoff

Comment: This looks like part of course work, are you being taught this comma separated join syntax? Please learn 'modern' (30 years old) `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax. It is much easier to read, write and alter (to outer joins, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, an expression or column referenced in your `SELECT` clause should either...

- be part of an aggregate *(`MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`, etc)*
- be mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause.

For example, what do you expect the following to return?

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 'foo', 10)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 'bar', 20)

SELECT a, b, SUM(c) FROM table GROUP BY a
```

Because of the `GROUP BY a`, you're only going to get one result row back.  But you're selecting `b` too.  Should it return `'foo'` or `'bar'`?

Although MySQL 5.x allows you to do this, it won't work in MySQL 8 or any other dialect of SQL.  It's bad practice, creates unexpected results, is harder to maintain, easier to make mistakes, and even MySQL recommend you don't do it.  *(There's even an option in MySQL 5.x to disallow this ambiguous code, but many hosts don't activate it by default.)*

As such, the above query should be one of the following...

```
SELECT a, b, SUM(c) FROM table GROUP BY a, b
-- or...
SELECT a, MAX(b), SUM(c) FROM table GROUP BY a
-- or...
SELECT a, MIN(b), SUM(c) FROM table GROUP BY a
-- etc, etc
```

In none of the above examples is anything ambiguous and none of the results will be arbitrary.

Also, don't join your tables with `,`.  ***ANSI-92*** is the standard adopted to replace that with explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It's very nearly 30 years old.  Which means you're using syntax that's Three Decades out of date.

For example, both of the following queries is wrong, but only the latter will throw an error ***telling*** you that it's wrong

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = 1
-- vs
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b WHERE a.id = 1
```

When the latter query throws the error it's then easy to make the  correction...

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE a.id = 1
```

Together, this means that your query ***should*** be...

```
select
  e.student_num as StudentID,
  s.student_name as Name,
  sum(c.num_credits*450) as Tuition
from
  students s
inner join
  enrolls  e
    on e.student_num = s.student_num
inner join
  sections se
    on se.section_id = e.section_id 
inner join
  courses c 
    on c.course_num = se.course_num
group by
  s.student_num,
  s.student_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The hints from the people who commented should be taken to heart. It will save you a great deal of pain in the future.

Here is an example of the *modern SQL* method, with a complete `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT e.student_num as StudentID,
       s.student_name as Name,
       SUM(c.num_credits * 450) as Tuition 
  FROM students s INNER JOIN enrolls e ON e.student_num = s.student_num
                  INNER JOIN sections se ON e.section_id = se.section_id
                  INNER JOIN courses c ON se.course_num = c.course_num
GROUP BY s.student_name;
```